Why does `systemfit` yield identical results for OLS and WLS?
I am estimating a system of seemingly unrelated regressions (SUR) using the systemfit package in R. Each of the equations has one unique regressor and one common regressor. I use two alternative estimation methods: ordinary least squares, OLS (method="OLS") and weighted least squares, WLS (method="WLS"), as discussed in section 2.1 (p. 3-4) of the systemfit vignette. I get the same point estimates and standard errors from both. The covariance matrices of coefficients are also identical. That puzzles me. Shouldn't the standard errors and more generally, the covariance matrices of coefficients differ?
Question: Why does systemfit yield identical results for method="OLS" and method="WLS"?
library(systemfit)

# Generate and prepare the data
n <- 1000 # sample size
m <- 100  # length of the "second part" of the sample
N <- 3    # number of eqations
set.seed(321); x <- matrix(rnorm(n*N), ncol=N); colnames(x) <- paste0("x", 1:N) # generate regressors
dummy <- c(rep(0, n-m), rep(1, m)) # generate a common regressor
x <- cbind(x, dummy)               # include the common regressor with the rest of the regressors
set.seed(123); y <- matrix(rnorm(n*N), ncol=N); colnames(y) <- paste0("y", 1:N) # a placeholder for dependent variables
for (i in 1:N) {
  y[, i] <- i + sqrt(i)*x[, i] - i*dummy + y[, i]*15*sqrt(i)   
  # y[, i] is a linear function of x[, i] and dummy, 
  # plus an error term with equation-specific variance - just what WLS is made for
}
data1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(y, x)) # create a data frame of all data (y and x)

# Create the model equations
eqSystem <- list() 
for (i in 1:N) {
  eqSystem[[i]] <- 
    as.formula(assign(paste0("eq", i), 
                      value=paste0("y", i, " ~ x", i, " + dummy"))) # define linear equations of SUR
}

# Estimate the model with `method="OLS"` and `method="WLS"`
m1 <- systemfit(formula=eqSystem, method="OLS", data=data1)
m2 <- systemfit(formula=eqSystem, method="WLS", data=data1)
summary(m1, residCov=FALSE, equations=FALSE)
summary(m2, residCov=FALSE, equations=FALSE)
m1$coefCov # covariance matrix of coefficients
m2$coefCov # covariance matrix of coefficients

A follow-up question: "Why does systemfit yield different results for OLS and WLS under cross-equation restrictions?"

@SextusEmpiricus, sorry about the code. You can print out intermediary results such as eqSystem to check what they are. There may be a typo (please let me know where), but I got the same paradoxical results with real data. This is where the question originated. I only use simulated data for reproducibility.

I thought there was a typo when you added y[,i] to y[,i],  but it was the concise coding. You used y[,i] as the error to be added to y[,i] which was confusing. (also, I am reading this from a phone so scrolling the lines is nog so easy).

Yes, I saved some memory by not creating a separate matrix of epsilons. Sorry about the confusion! I am hopeful to have you on this case! It is bed time for me now, but I will come back in the morning.

Somewhat related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645175

The weights only play a role when there are restrictions on the regression. Below is an example for
$$\begin{array}{}
 y_1 &=& a_1 + b_1 x_1 + \epsilon_1 \\
y_2& = &a_2 + b_2 x_2 + \epsilon_2 \\
\rlap{\text{with the condition $b_1 + b_2 = 0$}}
\end{array}$$
the restriction makes that the estimation of $b_1$ and $b_2$ are coupled. effectively we are guessing a single parameter:
$$\begin{array}{}
 y_1 &=& a_1 + b x_1 + \epsilon_1 \\
y_2& = &a_2 - b x_2 + \epsilon_2 \\
\end{array}$$
and this makes that the potential differences in variance of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ play a role.
Code example:
library(systemfit, quietly = TRUE)

# Generate and prepare the data
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000 # sample size
x1 = rnorm(n)
x2 = rnorm(n)
epsilon = rnorm(n)
y1 = 1 + x1 + epsilon
y2 = 1 - x2 + epsilon*2+rnorm(n)

### regressions
eqSystem <- list(eq1 = as.formula("y1~x1"),
                 eq2 = as.formula("y2~x2")) 


### perform fits 
restrict = matrix(c(0,1,0,1), ncol = 4)
rhs= c(0)


m1 <- systemfit(formula=eqSystem, 
                method="OLS", 
                control = systemfit.control(residCovWeighted = FALSE),
                restrict.matrix = restrict,
                restrict.rhs = rhs
)
m2 <- systemfit(formula=eqSystem, 
                method="WLS", 
                control = systemfit.control(residCovWeighted = TRUE),
                restrict.matrix = restrict,
                restrict.rhs = rhs
)

summary(m1, equations=FALSE)
summary(m2, equations=FALSE)


The covariance matrices of coefficients are also identical.

The difference between WLS and OLS methods is just that, after the OLS step, the WLS adds an extra weighted least squares step (equivalent to a GLS step with a diagonal covariance matrix). But those weights have no influence if the equations are without restrictions.
In the output you can see that the WLS has an extra covariance matrix
in my example this is:
The covariance matrix of the residuals used for estimation
        eq1     eq2
eq1 1.06489 0.00000
eq2 0.00000 5.38194

The covariance matrix of the residuals
        eq1     eq2
eq1 1.06201 2.13663
eq2 2.13663 5.38773 

This first diagonal matrix does not occur with OLS.

The OLS method just computes a single OLS step and makes an estimate of the covariance matrix.
Before computing the covariance matrix, the WLS method computes a weighted regression with a diagonal covariance matrix.

Without restrictions, the weights have only influence on the observations of a single equation, and they will be all the same weight for each row of observations within that single equation. So the extra step with the WLS method has effectively no influence on the fitted coefficients.
The regression of the multiple equations can be seen as a single equation that is stacked.
If the regressor matrices are like
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{1,1} &\text{dummy_{1,1}} \\
1 & x_{1,2} &\text{dummy_{1,2}}\\
1 & x_{1,3} &\text{dummy_{1,3}} \\
1 & x_{1,4} &\text{dummy_{1,4}}\\
1 & x_{1,5} &\text{dummy_{1,5}} \end{bmatrix} \quad 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{2,1} &\text{dummy_{2,1}} \\
1 & x_{2,2} &\text{dummy_{2,2}}\\
1 & x_{2,3} &\text{dummy_{2,3}} \\
1 & x_{2,4} &\text{dummy_{2,4}}\\
1 & x_{2,5} &\text{dummy_{2,5}} \end{bmatrix}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{3,1} &\text{dummy_{3,1}} \\
1 & x_{3,2} &\text{dummy_{3,2}}\\
1 & x_{3,3} &\text{dummy_{3,3}} \\
1 & x_{3,4} &\text{dummy_{3,4}}\\
1 & x_{3,5} &\text{dummy_{3,5}} \end{bmatrix}
$$
then the three regressions can be solved as a single regression
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{1,1} &\text{dummy_{1,1}}&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
1 & x_{1,2} &\text{dummy_{1,2}}&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1 & x_{1,3} &\text{dummy_{1,3}}&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
1 & x_{1,4} &\text{dummy_{1,4}}&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1 & x_{1,5} &\text{dummy_{1,5}} &0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1 & x_{2,1} &\text{dummy_{2,1}}&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1 & x_{2,2} &\text{dummy_{2,2}}&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1 & x_{2,3} &\text{dummy_{2,3}}&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1 & x_{2,4} &\text{dummy_{2,4}}&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1 & x_{2,5} &\text{dummy_{2,5}}&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1 & x_{3,1} &\text{dummy_{3,1}} \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1 & x_{3,2} &\text{dummy_{3,2}}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1 & x_{3,3} &\text{dummy_{3,3}} \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1 & x_{3,4} &\text{dummy_{3,4}}\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1 & x_{3,5} &\text{dummy_{3,5}} \end{bmatrix}$$
Multiplying this with a diagonal weights matrix will only multiply the columns of the same regression, and it doesn't change the fit.

You found a case where OLS and WLS are different, and that does not surprise me, as OLS and WLS are not the same estimator. What surprises me is the case where they are the same. I take your answer to suggest that without restrictions, point estimates and standard errors are algebraically the same in OLS and WLS. Is that true? And then what is different betwee them? Which elements of the covariance matrix $(X'\hat\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}$ are different? Here $\Omega:=\mathbb{E}(u u')=\Sigma\bigotimes I_T$ and $\hat\Omega$ must be different between OLS and WLS. (Notation from systemfit vignette.)

@RichardHardy the weights are irrelevant when there are no restrictions. Each coefficient is estimated with the same weights. Without restrictions, the weights of equation x have only influence on estimation of the parameters in equation x.

I believe they must be used for obtaining the system-wide covriance matrix $(X'\hat\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}$. However, it could happen that the part of that matrix that we see in the summary output (namely, the standard errors of individual coefficients) is not affected by the use of weights.

@RichardHardy the covariance matrix is estimated regardless of the weights (and later on used in a generalized least squares fit if you are using SUR method).

The weights are built in, they determine $\hat\Omega$. Am I mistaken?

@RichardHardy The estimate of $\hat\Omega$ is only used in further steps. The method OLS is only the single first step. The method WLS adds steps by refitting with a diagonal $\hat\Omega$. The method SUR will add steps by refitting with a non-diagonal $\hat\Omega$. If you do SUR with maxit>>1 then the residCovWeighted related to WLS versus OLS in the initial steps will have little or no effect because you converge to the same solution.

Let me think... Perhaps both of us are right? Here is a thought experiment: you estimate the unrestricted model and then use a Wald test to test some cross-equation restriction. I think you will get different results under OLS and WLS. So the estimation is unrestricted, yet the test results are different, which shows that the covariance matrices are different. I will try to write code for that and see whether the empirics support my conjecture. Update: I was wrong. There is really no difference between the coefficient covariance matrices and thus the test results.

The difference between WLS and OLS methods is just that the WLS adds an extra weighted least squares step (equivalent to a GLS step with a diagonal covariance matrix) after an initial OLS step. But those weights have no influence if the equations are without restrictions.

If you summarized all of the above by editing your answer, I would be happy to upvote. I still do not exactly see why things are what they are (I do not see an intuitive algebraic proof), but I think I will be able to grasp that. One of the things that still confuse me is that $\hat\Omega$ is not diagonal; it is a Kronecker product of something times an identity matrix, so it has many diagonal blocks that are all the same. So it is not obvious that it cancels out when obtaining point estimates where we "multiply" and later "divide" by $\hat\Omega$.

It is even less obvious how $\hat\Omega^{-1}$ has absolutely no effect on $(X'\hat\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}$, as if $\hat\Omega^{-1}=I$...

Without restrictions, the weights of equation x have only influence on estimation of the parameters in equation x Since the weights are for equations - not observations - do they really have an influence on estimation of the parameters in a given equation? Multiplying this with a diagonal weights matrix will only multiply the columns of the same regression, and it doesn't change the fit. The weights matrix is not diagnonal, it is based on $\Omega=\Sigma\bigotimes I_T$, but the zero blocks in $X$ make things simpler.

@RichardHardy for the WLS step the estimated covariance of the error terms is a diagonal matrix. See the matrix in the code output under The covariance matrix of the residuals used for estimation, it is the additional GLS fit with that additional diagonal covariance matrix that makes the WLS method different from the OLS method.

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares#Weighted_least_squares „A special case of GLS, called weighted least squares (WLS), occurs when all the off-diagonal entries of Ω are 0.”

The covariance matrix of the residuals used for estimation is some version of $\Sigma$, not of $\Omega$.

@RichardHardy I am not acquainted with the notation and what $I_T$ means. This sounds like converting the N x N matrix for the covariance of the errors in the N equations into a nN x nN matrix for the covariance of the errors in the nN columns in the combined regressor matrix? Anyway, it should just as well end up with a diagonal matrix.

Regarding the notation, I am using pages 2-4 of the vignette. Yes, $I_T$ is identity matrix of dimension $T$ where $T$ is the number of observations in each equation. And I have written it out in detail (by hand on paper) and convinced myself it is not a diagonal matrix. Yes, It is made of diagonal blocks, but these blocks are everywhere, not only on the main diagonal. Anyway, they seem to do no harm if the inverse of $\Sigma\bigotimes I_t$ has the same shape as $\Sigma\bigotimes I_t$ itself. I am trying to look that up (what is the inverse of a Kronecker product where the second matrix is I).

@RichardHardy that makes it what I thought. If $\Sigma$ is diagonal, then $\Omega$ will be diagonal as well.

@RichardHardy For 3 equations the product is $$\Omega = \Sigma \otimes I_k = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{1,1} I_{k} & \Sigma_{1,2} I_{k} & \Sigma_{1,3} I_{k} \
\Sigma_{2,1} I_{k} & \Sigma_{2,2} I_{k} & \Sigma_{2,3} I_{k} \
\Sigma_{3,1} I_{k} & \Sigma_{3,2} I_{k} & \Sigma_{3,3} I_{k} \ \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{1,1} I_{k} & 0 & 0 \
0 & \Sigma_{2,2} I_{k} &0 \
0 & 0 & \Sigma_{3,3} I_{k} \ \end{bmatrix}
$$ where the second equation is true if $\Sigma$ is diagonal.

My previous comment had an equation wrong, so I have deleted it. My head is cloudy today. Thank you so much for you patience!

I have posted an answer where I calculate the coefficient covariance matrices manually and show that... What? Well, not sure exactly how to call that, but you can take a look.

I am now trying to understand why OLS and WLS differ when there are some linear restrictions on the parameters. According to equations (26) and (27) of the vignette, the only thing that could be different between OLS and WLS is $\hat\Omega$. However, we have seen that they are identical. So how come the restricted estimates are different?

@RichardHardy the $\hat{\Omega}$ is different for OLS vs WLS when used for fitting, but in computing the standard error they seem to be using the same $\hat{\Omega}$. E.g. if you have some heteroscedastic data and ignore it by fitting OLS instead of WLS, then after that you may still use information about the different variance in the errors to compute the standard error of the OLS fit. So the method = "OLS" ignores heteroscedasticity when fitting but not when estimating the error.

What is the difference then? Do they use control = systemfit.control(singleEqSigma = FALSE) in one but control = systemfit.control(singleEqSigma = TRUE) in the other? This is really confusing... (I think I will post a separate question based on my previous comment.)

@RichardHardy The difference between OLS and WLS is that they use different weights when fitting (and that has an effect if there are restrictions), but they do not differ when estimating the error in which case they will use an estimate of the covariance of the errors based on the residuals. (the use of different weights can be expressed in terms of a covariance matrix $\hat{\Omega}$, when fitting with GLS, and that resembles the use of a covariance matrix $\hat{\Omega}$ when estimating the error, but those two are different. The one is estimated and used before fitting, the other after.)

OK, I have posted a new question here.

So in the new post, I tried replicating the restricted OLS and restricted WLS estimators manually. For OLS, I am not getting the right result, and I do not know why. For WLS, I do not know what $\hat\Omega$ I should use, whereas if I use the same one as for OLS (corresponding to control = systemfit.control(singleEqSigma = FALSE)) my result does not match anything from systemfit.

A big THANK YOU for all your help! It was incredible to have you guide me so patiently through all of this!

With a ton of patient guidance by Sextus Empiricus, I got convinced that the point estimates from OLS and WLS are not supposed to differ. (Note: I did not claim the opposite in the OP, but I was unsure and lost in detail.) However, I was still puzzled by the fact that the estimated covariance matrices of the coefficients do not differ in systemfit. Using the notation from the systemfit vignette, the estimated covariance matrix is $\widehat{\text{Cov}}(\hat\beta)=(X'\hat\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}$ (equation 8 on p. 3).

In the case of OLS, $$\hat\Omega_{\text{OLS}}=\hat\sigma^2 I_{TG}\color{red}{^*}$$ where $T$ is the number of observations (n in my code) and $G$ the number of equations (N in my code).
In the case of WLS, $$\hat\Omega_{\text{OLS}}=\hat\Sigma \bigotimes I_{T}$$ where the elements $\hat\sigma_{ij}$ of $\hat\Sigma$ are such: $\hat\sigma_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $\hat\sigma_{ii}=\sigma_i^2$, so the latter is the estimated variance of the disturbance terms in the $i$th equation.

I do not see how
$$\widehat{\text{Cov}}_{\text{OLS}}(\hat\beta)=(X'\hat\Omega_{\text{OLS}}^{-1}X)^{-1}$$
is the same as
$$\widehat{\text{Cov}}_{\text{WLS}}(\hat\beta)=(X'\hat\Omega_{\text{WLS}}^{-1}X)^{-1}.$$
The following R code illustrates manual calculations of $\widehat{\text{Cov}}_{\text{OLS}}(\hat\beta)$ and $\widehat{\text{Cov}}_{\text{WLS}}(\hat\beta)$.$\color{red}{^{**}}$ It requires running the code of the OP first.
# Manually construct the X matrix corresponding to equation (2) from the vignette
O_N3=matrix(0,nrow=n,ncol=N); 
X=rbind( cbind( cbind(1,x[,c(1,N+1)]),O_N3                 ,O_N3                  ) , 
         cbind( O_N3                 ,cbind(1,x[,c(2,N+1)]),O_N3                  ) , 
         cbind( O_N3                 ,O_N3                 ,cbind(1,x[,c(3,N+1)]) ) )
#round(X,2)

# Obtain $\widehat{Cov}_{OLS}(\hat\beta)$ and compare to the output from `systemfit`
sigma2=var(unlist(resid(m1)))
cov_inv_OLS= 1/sigma2 * t(X) %*% X
cov_OLS=solve(cov_inv_OLS)
round(cov_OLS,4)
round(m1$coefCov,4)
round(cov_OLS/m1$coefCov,4) 
# The ratio of estimated covariances between my solution and that of `systemfit` 
# is constant per equation. However, it differs across equations. 

# Obtain $\widehat{Cov}_{WLS}(\hat\beta)$ and compare to the output from `systemfit`
cov_inv_WLS = t(X) %*% solve(diag(diag(m2$residCov)) %x% diag(n)) %*% X
cov_WLS = solve(cov_inv_WLS)
round(cov_WLS,4)
round(m2$coefCov,4)
round(cov_WLS/m2$coefCov,4)
# The ratio of estimated covariances between my solution and that of `systemfit` is 1.

I am able to replicate the systemfit result for WLS but not OLS. It seems to me systemfit is doing WLS instead of OLS - contrary to what the vignette claims at the bottom of p. 3 and the first sentence on p. 4. However, right after that it presents the alternative of defining the OLS estimator in exactly the same way as they define the WLS estimator a few lines below, and that seems to be the definition of OLS that they actually implement. (Compare lines 3-5 of p. 4 with lines 3-5 of the subsection Weighted Least Squares (WLS) on the same page.) Not sure what to conclude from all that, but at least we see some details...
$\color{red}{^*}$Actually, the vignette says $\hat\Omega_{\text{OLS}}^{-1}=I_{TG}$, so it misses the factor $\hat\sigma^2$. Correct me if I am wrong.
$\color{red}{^{**}}$Sorry about less than elegant code. Print some intermediate results to convince yourselves that it is doing what it is doing. Set n=8, m=2 and N=3 in the code of the OP for more transparent results.

The OLS and WLS method parameter are related to the fitting, but not to the estimation of the error where the heteroscedasticity or homoscedasticity is regulated with the control parameter. With the setting  control = systemfit.control(singleEqSigma = FALSE) the error estimation will not use a seperate sigma for each seperate equation.

@SextusEmpiricus, thanks!
