SUR estimated via `systemfit` vs `sysGmm`: different standard errors
I am estimating a system of seemingly unrelated regressions (SUR) in R. Each of the equations has one unique regressor and one common regressor. I have two alternative implementations: one via systemfit::systemfit and the other via gmm::sysGmm. I get the same point estimates from both, but the standard errors differ. That is unexpected, as I do not think there exist different versions of the concept of SUR.
Question: Why are the standard errors of SUR from systemfit and sysGmm different?
library(systemfit)
library(gmm)

# Generate and prepare the data
n <- 1000 # sample size
m <- 100  # length of the "second part" of the sample
N <- 3    # number of eqations
set.seed(123); y <- matrix(rnorm(n*N),ncol=N); colnames(y) <- paste0("y",1:N) # generate dependent variables
set.seed(321); x <- matrix(rnorm(n*N),ncol=N); colnames(x) <- paste0("x",1:N) # generate regressors
dummy <- c( rep(0,n-m), rep(1,m) ) # generate a common regressor
x <- cbind(x,dummy)                # include the common regressor with the rest of the regressors
data1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,x)) # create a data frame of all data (y and x)

# Create the model equations and moment conditions
eqSystem_g = eqSystem_h <- list() 
for(i in 1:N){
 eqSystem_g[[i]] <- as.formula(assign(paste0("eq",i), value=paste0("y",i," ~ x",i," + dummy"))) # define linear equations of SUR
 eqSystem_h[[i]] <- as.formula(assign(paste0("eq",i), value=paste0(       "~ x",i," + dummy"))) # define the moment conditions for GMM
}

# Estimate the model with `systemfit` and `sysGmm`
m1 <- systemfit::systemfit(formula=eqSystem_g, method="SUR", data=data1)
m2 <- gmm::sur(g=eqSystem_g, data=data1)
summary(m1, residCov=FALSE, equations=FALSE)
summary(m2)

 Related: 
* System GMM yields identical results for any weighting matrix 
* Why does systemfit yield identical results for OLS and WLS? 
* Why does systemfit yield different results for OLS and WLS under cross-equation restrictions? 

Somewhat related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645173

Wow, they differ by a lot!  I tried setting the number of iterations to 10 in the systemfit routine and it made essentially no difference, just to rule out one possibility.

I would guess that systemfit is correct because it corresponds to the error with lm which I would expect to be the same for this example. It is difficult to see how sysGmm:sur computed the covariance because it is much described in the documents.

I recommend you use the momenfit package instead. If you run the following after your code, you will get very similar standard errors. The difference is probably due to degrees of freedom corrections.
library(momentfit)
h <- lapply(1:3, function(i) ~x1+x2+x3+dummy)
smod <- sysMomentModel(eqSystem_g, data=data1)
fit <- gmmFit(smod)
sfit <- summary(fit)

I have to say that gmm is not well suited for systems of equations. The main reason is that estimating systems of equations is in general not recommended. It is too sensitive to identification failures (problems in one equation spread to the others), so the efficiency gain is in general not worth it. This being say, I will fix the problem and update it on RForge.

Thank you! That solves it. The second line in your code does not seem to do anything relevant to this problem, so I suppose it is safe to skip it? Regarding the use of GMM for systems of equations, I am not doing it for efficiency but for HC or HAC robust standard errors. In my context, model specification is not an issue; each of the equations is fine, so I am not worried about mistakes spreading to estimates in other equations. (If that is what you meant by indentification failures.) I would do SUR via systemfit but am concerned about non-i.i.d. errors, so I use system GMM to fix that.

Correct about the second line not being relevant. And it makes sense if looking for robust s.e.  The problem with the standard errors has been fixed in version 1.9 of the gmm  package available on Rforge.
